# How to add Row_number to table function results

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a function that returns groups(clusters) from a table..

```
create function dbo.ftAllClusters() returns table as return
select distinct Cluster from Company
```

Now I need to add RowNumber for each of the row returned..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Cluster, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Cluster) AS RowNo
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Cluster
    FROM Company
) x
```

Or...

```
SELECT Cluster, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Cluster) AS RowNo
FROM Company
GROUP BY Cluster
```

Comment: Second option seems less expensive(Interms of perfomance).. voted up

Comment: I think they may end up with the same execution plan (very quick/basic test shows they do). But I think the 2nd is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

There is build in Function in SQL called [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

**EDIT:**
According to comment by losing distinct function in order by
You can try to SubSelet

```
    create function dbo.ftAllClusters() returns table as return
    Select 
       Cluster
      ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (order by Cluster)) as RN
   from (
         Select 
          distinct 
          ,Cluster
          from Company ) as Comp
```

Or You can try using Group BY instead of Distinc ( I even think that that is little bit faster )

```
Select 
   Cluster
  ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (order by Cluster)) as RN
from Company 
group by Cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I worked out, Is there a better way ?

```
ALTER function dbo.ftAllClusters() returns table as return
With CTE(comno) as
(select distinct Cluster from  company)

select id=Row_number() over(order by comno),comno from cte
```